# How can I implement JMX in my java code to show measure on JMX counter

Tags: jmx, spring-jmx

How can I implement JMX in my java code to show measure  on JMX counter.
what XML file I need like MBEAN. Please I need some guidance its very imp.

I ultimately build a jar file and run from the terminal . So what all to implement there in the code needs to be done?

Comment: You might find https://github.com/statsbiblioteket/jmx-simple-demo interesting.  It defines and exposes a MXBean and updates its values.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Spring, I would start in the Spring docs here: [JMX](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jmx.html). The documentation is well written and describes exactly how to do this.

Comment: Yeah , I have read it before but do you think as I already have a code where I just need to implement a JMX as on the server side . I have already Implement

Comment: import org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.ManagedAttribute;
import org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.ManagedResource;

Comment: @ManagedResource(objectName = "com.carrieriq:name=AssemblyLineStreamer", description = "This bean will allows " + "Some executions for the binary feed process")                        @ManagedAttribute(description="RTI: Gets the maximum execution")
 public int getExecutions() {
  return mExecutions;                                                                   but this is not enough to show mw my JMX counters on jconsole what else I need

Comment: So do you think all I need is to implement a BEAN other than the work I have done?

Comment: yeah sure I can .

Comment: Its a very big code actually But let me try to post something more meaningful.

Comment: I am not able to post the code as its a big code so it has indentation problem.

Comment: How about a gist ?

Comment: Okay let me see what I can do about it. I have to push the code there. let me try . Just wanted to ask you , so what if we want to call and JMX implemented code into an bean .

Comment: Lets suppose I have code x where there is complete implementation of the JMX and Mbean. I want to know that if I have a code Y where there is no jmx and I want to use the properties of the JMX from the code X which is in different package altogether thru bean how can that be possible. I havent gone thru that document bcz of lot of pending work . But just wanted to know in general.

Comment: Sure. Using Spring, you can inject the instance of X into the instance of Y and delegate all the JMX calls from Y to X.